# How to disable the buffering of messages on an Akka WebSocket server?

Tags: scala, websocket, akka, akka-http

I have a very simple Akka WebSocket server that pushes lines from a file to a connected client with an interval of 400ms per line. Everything works fine, except for the fact that the web server seems to buffer messages for about a minute before broadcasting them.

So when a client connects, I see at the server end that every 400ms a line is read and pushed to the `Sink`, but on the client side I get nothing for a minute and then a burst of about 150 messages (corresponding to a minute of messages).

Is there a setting that I'm overlooking?

```
object WebsocketServer extends App {
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("WebsocketServer")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher

  val file = Paths.get("websocket-server/src/main/resources/EURUSD.txt")
  val fileSource =
    FileIO.fromPath(file)
      .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), Int.MaxValue))

  val delayedSource: Source[Strict, Future[IOResult]] =
    fileSource
      .map { line =>
        Thread.sleep(400)
        println(line.utf8String)
        TextMessage(line.utf8String)
      }

  def route = path("") {
    extractUpgradeToWebSocket { upgrade =>
      complete(upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(
        Sink.ignore,
        delayedSource)
      )
    }
  }

  val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)

  bindingFuture.onComplete {
    case Success(binding) ⇒
      println(s"Server is listening on ws://localhost:8080")
    case Failure(e) ⇒
      println(s"Binding failed with ${e.getMessage}")
      actorSystem.terminate()
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know where the pause is occurring, on the server or the client side? You might want to use tcpdump or similar.

Comment: From the server. I use Dark WebSocket Terminal as (test) client and it doesn't have this issue with other streams, so it must be server side. 
But I'll try tcpdump as well and let you know if I find something different that is not a serverside issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the approach with `Thread.sleep(400)` was wrong. I should've used the `.throttle` mechanic on sources:

```scala
val delayedSource: Source[Strict, Future[IOResult]] =
    fileSource
      .throttle(elements = 1, per = 400.millis)
      .map { line =>
        println(line.utf8String)
        TextMessage(line.utf8String)
      }
```

This fixed the issue.